# How to combine seperate apps into one webpage?

Tags: python, html, django

To my understanding Django is all about DRY and plug and play architecture with reusable apps. I'm trying to create my own Portfolio website using as proper and neat coding as I can. Given that, im trying to keep my apps independent so if I wanted, or anyone else, they could use it themselves. The problem is that I have my apps completely created but I'm trying to map them to one home page instead of blahblah.com/Messaging and blahblah.com/Projects

I have two seperate apps, one a messaging form so someone can contact me, and another so I can list projects that I would display on the site. Here is my current code.

My directory structure

```
/PortfolioWebsite
 /Messaging
    /migrations
    /templates
      /Messaging (namespaced as Django recommends)
        Messagingtem.html
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    tests.py
    forms.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
 /PortfolioWebsite
   __init.py
   asgi.py
   settings.py
   urls.py
   wsgi.py
 /Projects
   /migrations
   /static
     /Projects (namespaced as Django recommends)
       /images
         projectimage1.jpg
         projectimage2.jpg
   /templates
     /Projects (namespaced as Django recommends)
       projectbase_list.html
   __init__.py
   admin.py
   apps.py
   models.py
   tests.py
   urls.py
   views.py
 /templates
   base.html (used for bootstrap)
 db.sqlite3
 manage.py
```

Dunno if that was needed, just wanted to give an idea.

My views.py for Messaging:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import MessageForm
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
# Create your views here.
class MessageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'Messaging\Messagingtem.html'
    def get(self, request):
        form = MessageForm
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
    def post(self, request):
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('MessageView')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Template for messaging:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class= 'Container' id="Messagingtem">
    <div class= 'form-row'>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for='message_text'>Feel free to send me a message!</label>
            <div>
                <label for='message_text'>
                    {% if form.errors %}
                        {% for field in form %}
                            {% for error in field.errors %}
                                {{ error|escape }}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                 </label>
            </div>
            {{form.name_text}}
            {{form.email_text}}
            {{form.message_text}}
            <button type="submit" class='btn btn-Primary'>Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-Primary">Close</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Views for Projects:

```
from .models import ProjectBase
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class ProjectListView(ListView):
    model = ProjectBase
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

Template for projects:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block page_content %}
<div class="Container">
    <div class="row">
        {% for project in object_list %}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card mb-2">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{% static project.image %}">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{ project.title }}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ project.description }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**How do I get these separate independent apps on a single homepage?**

Answer (score 2):

You would just need to import the models from the other apps, and then use a Class Based View to merge the information into the context. I would recommend creating a new app called "Main" and then importing the other models into it.

For example (Main/Views.py):

```
from django.views.generic import View
from Messaging.models import Model1, Model2
from Projects.models import ModelA, ModelB

class IndexView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Generate forms & filter models here, then add to `{}` below
        render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm a little confused. So this solution requires writing the views over again and passing it as context? Also what about the templates? Sorry i dont understand

Comment: @ChrisFire The new answer you made is pretty much the best way to go about it - otherwise you could remove the redundant code and just redirect to the index page (although you would lose the error messages)

Comment: Thank you, I can sleep at night a little now.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of using the solution given by Hybrid, this is what I got to work. ***It feels sloppy and I feel like there is some better way to do this***, but it will work for now I guess.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import View
from Messaging.models import Message
from Messaging.forms import MessageForm
from Projects.models import ProjectBase

class Indexview(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = MessageForm
        Projects = ProjectBase.objects.all()
        context = {'form': form, 'Projects' : Projects}
        return render(request, 'Integration/index.html', context)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        Projects = ProjectBase.objects.all()
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('Portfolio')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
        context = {'form': form, 'Projects': Projects}
        return render(request, 'Integration/index.html', context)
```

For the template "index.html", it's just the same thing combined except variable object_list turned to Projects as defined in the view context.

If anyone could give smoother or more optimal code that doesn't violate DRY principles, that would be great.